# Silverstripe - Overwrite Image.php - possibilities?

Tags: php, silverstripe

Whenever Silverstripe creates from an image a resized version the system will also generate a webp version of this image.
Via `.htaccess` I can then forward user with chrome browser to this `webp image`.

My idea was so far to extend the `image.php` class, the problem is, that an extension can not overwrite an existing method.

Is there any way that I can do something so that I can do this still when I call `$Image.setWidth(200)` from the template, my function will be run?

My aim is still to prevent changing all methodnames which would work.
`$Image.webpSetWidth(200)` would work with a normal image extension. But if somehow possible I would avoid this.

Checked the `Image.php` (and `GD.php`) for possibilities to extend it, but at least in `Silverstripe 3.6` it is not possible.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the hints of Brett I got pointed into the right direction.

```
<?php

    class WebPGDBackend extends GDBackend
    {
        public function writeTo($filename)
        {
            parent::writeTo($filename);

            if (function_exists('imagewebp')) {
                $picname = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $directory = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);
                switch ($type) {
                            case 2:
                                if (function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg')) {
                                    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                                    $webp = imagewebp($img, $directory.'/'.$picname.'.webp');
                                    $gif = imagegif($img, $directory.'/'.$picname.'.gif');
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                if (function_exists('imagecreatefrompng')) {
                                    $img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
                                    imagesavealpha($img, true); // save alphablending setting (important)
                                    $webp = imagewebp($img, $directory.'/'.$picname.'.webp');
                                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will create, whenever a resized image is saved (in jp(e)g/png format) a webp copy.
In order that this works it is necessary that gdlib is compiled with the appropriate flag.
Furthermore you will have to add the class to the config.php via 
`Image::set_backend("WebPGDBackend");`.

Keep in mind this will just work right now for graphics which gets newly resized.

With that above it would be possible to configure the `.htaccess`to forward jpeg/png requests for browsers which understand `webp` to the new graphic.

I realized that with the following snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Check if browser support WebP images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp

# Check if WebP replacement image exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f

# Serve WebP image instead
RewriteRule (assets.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if SS 3.6 has out of the box functionality which would generate this, however you can use the ImagickBackend and modify it through extensions to suit.

E.g.

```
<?php

if(class_exists('Imagick')) { 
class MyImagickBackend extends ImagickBackend {

    // default format to use
    private static $format = 'webp';

    public function __construct($filename = null) {
        parent::__construct($filename);
        $this->setImageFormat( Config::inst()->get('MyImagickBackend','format') );
    }
}
```

then in `_config.php` you just set the backend to use for Images

```
Image::set_backend("MyImagickBackend");
```

**NOTE:** This does require ImageMagick to be installed and the PHP module to be enabled.

**NOTE:** This has not been tested directly, so you may need to set other ImageMagick parameters for webp

**References:**

[Imagemagick Specific webp calls in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711492/imagemagick-specific-webp-calls-in-php)

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.6/filesystem/ImagickBackend.php

Comment: First of all. Thanks for that input. This pointed me into the right direction. Unfortunately I can not use Imagick, but my GD Lib has support for WebP.

Still a lot to do, but I will work on that. Maybe this will be a module in a few days. In that case, I post here an update with the github link in that case.